# How to send bulk emails using a Gmail email alias (changing Mailapp.SendEmail to Gmailapp.SendEmail)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm no expert with coding but I have a piece of code that works to send emails in bulk via Google Sheets. I want to change it so that it send from an alias that I've already set up in my Gmail settings. I would really appreciate it if someone would be able show me how I can change the piece of code below to do this. Thanks in advance!

```
function SendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(2, 10).getValue();
  var htmlBody = sheet.getRange(3, 10).getValue();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1];
      var name = row[0];
      var CID = row[2];
      var companyName = row[3];
      var variable1 = row[4];
      var variable2 = row[5];
      var variable3 = row[6];
      var newSubject = subject.replace(/COMPANY/g, companyName);
      var replaced1 = htmlBody.replace(/CLIENT/g, name);
      var replaced2 = replaced1.replace(/COMPANY/g, companyName);
      var replaced3 = replaced2.replace(/CID/g, CID);
      var replaced4 = replaced3.replace(/VAR1/g, variable1);
      var replaced5 = replaced4.replace(/VAR2/g, variable2);
      var replaced6 = replaced5.replace(/VAR3/g, variable3);
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: newSubject,
        htmlBody: replaced6,
        })
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of MailApp you need to use GmailApp.

```
 function SendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(2, 10).getValue();
  var htmlBody = sheet.getRange(3, 10).getValue();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1];
      var name = row[0];
      var CID = row[2];
      var companyName = row[3];
      var variable1 = row[4];
      var variable2 = row[5];
      var variable3 = row[6];
      var newSubject = subject.replace(/COMPANY/g, companyName);
      var replaced1 = htmlBody.replace(/CLIENT/g, name);
      var replaced2 = replaced1.replace(/COMPANY/g, companyName);
      var replaced3 = replaced2.replace(/CID/g, CID);
      var replaced4 = replaced3.replace(/VAR1/g, variable1);
      var replaced5 = replaced4.replace(/VAR2/g, variable2);
      var replaced6 = replaced5.replace(/VAR3/g, variable3);
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, newSubject, null, {
    from: aliases[0], //Replace with aliase
    htmlBody: replaced6,
  })
  })(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anees for your help, but it is still coming back with an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (line 29, file "Code.gs")". I'm not sure what I am suppose to do. Do you have any idea? Really appreciate your help :)